# Как в android studio сделать такой SeekBar

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать такой SeekBar

Comment: можно поискать кастомные seekbar-ы на гитхабе

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

1. Рисуете пустую полосу загрузки
2. Рисуете синие линии
3. Рисуете кружок
4. Прикручиваете код, который это всё отображает.